# Twilio Safe User Inputs in PHP

Tags: php, input, save, twilio

Hello guys I have this problem with twilio.
I have this kind of situation when user calls and enter his zipcode.
How can I store or save the Digits:

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";?>

<Response>
 <Gather numDigits="5" action="get.php" method="POST">
    <Say>Please enter the 5 digit zipcode.</Say>
</Gather>
```

Comment: If you look at this tutorial you can see that the digits entered by the user are posted to the same script that is running. You can check the post content to decide if this is a new request or one triggered from digits being entered https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-in-php

Comment: Andy my question was how to store the digits in a txt file or something like that.

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of resources you can use to find out the basics of PHP db or file access. Do some research, try out some code and if you have a specific question then please come back and ask it showing where you are stuck.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I have to agree with Andy here, I'd love to help out here, but you need to have a specific question and show what you've tried. If you can update your question with what you've tried, we'll try to help.

Comment: Guys, the question is simple. How can I save the digits user inputs into his phone over the call. For example you call my number and I ask for your zipcode, you enter the 5 digits and how can my IVR store that?

Comment: I'm willing to pay for this app if someone can develop.

Comment: Do you have a database and have you looked into using that to store the details from the call? This isn't a simple question because there is no context around how you actually want this information stored. I'd like to help, but you're not giving enough direction or showing what you've tried for storing the data yourself yet.

Comment: phil I'm really sorry but I don't know how to do the database in order to save the caller digits. can you show me an example or guide somewhere?